# What Units is Input.acceleration in for Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Same goes for Time.deltaTime, etc...  Are they all standardized to m/s^2 and s.
Would the below code encounter unit mistakes, or work fine?

```
public static void update()
{
    Vector3 a = Input.acceleration;
    v = v + Time.deltaTime * a;
    s = s +  Time.deltaTime * v;

    tm_dta += Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Comment: I think it's the same unit as unity's unit. it means if one unity unit represents 1 meter, it's 1m/s^2

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are all standardized to m/s^2 and s. 
However, for distance, one unit can really be anything you want. See link: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/45892/unity-unit-scale.html

Time.deltaTime is in seconds: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html